# What are the chords here?

Tags: chords

I'm studying Andate no. 6: in 'Studi per Chitarra' by Ferdinando Carulli
[image]

but I can't figure out what the '?' chords are. He could be syncopating but I feel that is unlikely because this was written sometime in the late classical era.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically a V or V7 chord, but using F# as an auxiliary tone to intensify the G.

Comment: Could also be read as a V7♯ chord.

Comment: @Lazy You mean a major seventh chord? I don't think that interpretation would hold up. The way to test it would be to play the piece, but where the F#-G part is, just replace it with a half-note GM7 chord and see if it sounds "right".

Comment: If you feel like applying Jazz chord semantics to late classical era, well, yes. Playing with minor seventh and major seventh on the dominant is non untypical for this era — especially when placed as 2-chord. Note for example to similar passage in Mozart’s KV545. From the voice leading it is clear that the f♯ does not serve as a suspension to the g, but as a Alberti style representation of two different voices, with the f♯ in the bass flattening to f or resolving to e (as expected from the seventh). All in all the f♯ behaves like we’d expect from a seventh. Imo this holds up quite well ...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really represent a chord at all. Not every note in a piece needs to have a chord assigned to it. Where did that notion come from?

Although the F♯ doesn't in fact belong to the prevalent G7 chord, those F♯s are there as an embellishment of the G notes. In much the same way as the motifs in Beethoven's Fur Elise.